# Twitter4J tweet entities?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J for getting search results back from Twitter. I recently heard about a feature called [tweet-entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) and according to some posts on the [mailing list of Twitter4J](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter4j/Tk3OsZXBDsc/qJ_NlMP54qYJ) it is supported but I can't seem to find any examples or figure out how to set my searches to include entities. How do I achieve this? I'm searching twitter by using something like the following...

```
 twitter.search("Searching Twitter with this query");
```

where `twitter` is of type Twitter

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not yet supported by twitter4j. You can create an issue for that. The functionality is still fresh in the twitter API, so perhaps it will appear in the next release of twitter4j.

In all other API requests (apart from search) the entities are included by default.